# How to regularly refresh the stock's price in cross-sectional engine

Tags: dolphindb

How to regularly refresh the stock's price in cross-sectional engine?

The aggregator table of a cross-sectional engine can be a result table. If I want to refresh the price for a stock regularly, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The cross section table in DolphinDB can provide an intermediate data table for aggregate calculation, but the cross section table can also be the final result. For example, we need to refresh the latest trading price of a certain stock regularly. The conventional idea is to screen the stocks by code from the real-time trading table and retrieve the last record. The data volume of the trading table increases rapidly over time. If you do this frequently the query, no matter from the resource consumption of the system or the performance of the query, it is not the best practice. The cross-sectional table always only saves the latest transaction data of all stocks, and the data volume is stable, which is very suitable for this kind of timing polling scenario.
To use the cross-section table as the result, you need to blank the two parameters of metrics and outputTable when creating the cross-section.
The sample code is as follows:

```py
def clearEnv(){    
unsubscribeTable(server="", tableName="trades", actionName="tradesCrossAggregator")    dropAggregator("CrossSectionalDemo") 
    undef("trades", SHARED) 
    undef("outputTable", SHARED) 
}
def writeData(n, trades){
    for (i in 0:n) {
        timev = take(now(), 3)
        symv   = rand(`A`B`C, 3)
           pricev = rand(10.0, 3)
           qtyv   = rand(10 20 30 , 3)
        insert into trades values(timev, symv, pricev,qtyv)
        sleep(1000)
    }
}

login("admin", "123456")//clearEnv()//undef all
share(streamTable(10:0, `time`sym`price`qty, [TIMESTAMP, SYMBOL, DOUBLE, INT]), "trades") share(table(1:0, `updateTime`maxQty`maxDollarVolume`sumDollarVolume`count, [TIMESTAMP, INT, DOUBLE, DOUBLE, INT]), "outputTable") tradesCrossAggregator=createCrossSectionalAggregator(name="CrossSectionalDemo", dummyTable=objByName("trades"), keyColumn="sym", triggeringPattern="perRow")subscribeTable(server="", tableName="trades", actionName="tradesCrossAggregator", offset=-1, handler=append!{tradesCrossAggregator}, msgAsTable=true)

submitJob("jobId","writeDataTrades",writeData{20, objByName("trades")})

select * from tradesCrossAggregator
```